# Why do property setters and getters clash with get_X and set_X methods?

Tags: .net, properties, language-design

In `.NET` properties are supposed to be first class citizens however in the `IL` code property getters and setters are implemented as `get_`*PropertyName* and `set_`*PropertyName*.

```
class Property
{
    int Value { get { return 42; } }
    int get_Value() { return 6 * 9; }
    void set_Value(int i) { } // Error even though Value is a read only property
}
```

**Output:**

> error CS0082: Type 'SO.Property' already reserves a member called 'get_Value' with the same parameter types
>
> error CS0082: Type 'SO.Property' already reserves a member called 'set_Value' with the same parameter types

Why did the designers of `.NET` decide to use a name that may clash with user code? They could have used an illegal character (as Java uses `$` for inner class stuff).

Comment: The get_Value() and set_Value() formats also go against the C# Naming Conventions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx): "Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters."

It may be precisely because of this very issue, but the point stands that you shouldn't be using this format in your C# code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For languages that don't have the concept of properties, such as J# (which may very well have influenced that design decision), it's still necessary to have a simple name to call them.

Answer (score 8):

The [Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) (CLS) requires the use of get_ and set_ methods in the IL (decorated with special bits) when implementing Properties. This is necessary so that different compilers (C#, managed C++, VB.NET, J#, IronPython, etc.) create interoperable bytecodes.

Thus underscores **are** not "legal" characters in the broader sense. They are not CLS-compliant and therefore should not be used in non-private interfaces.

Also, see this article about [writing CLS-compliant code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx) on the MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Because they may need to be called from external code.

Comment: No, "external" to C# - see Jb Evains answer

Answer (score 1):

Good question - most of the compiler-generated members (anonymous types and methods) use names that are guaranteed to not clash with any members in your class.  I think this particular instance (as well as the generated names for event methods) is a case where Microsoft made a little bit of a mistake.

The only reason I can think of that would justify the decision is that Microsoft may have been hoping to allow other languages to call these methods that do not themselves have a "property" concept or syntax.

Comment: not so much a mistake, it was deliberate. This indeed makes it easier for languages that do not support the notion of properties to call them, it also makes it easy to get the gettor or settor by reflection.